# How can I use the ternary operator with multiple values?

Tags: ruby

Hi I'm trying to understand why my code seems to work in the if/else form but doesn't seem to work with the ternary operator.

For the true value I want that it reduces the balance and puts my message.

Below is what I have tried:

```
# With ternary operator. This doesn't work:

def withdraw(pin_number, amount)
    puts pin_number == pin ? @balance -= amount "Withdrew #{amount}. New 
    balance $#{@balance}." : puts pin_error
end

# With if/else statement. This does work:

def withdraw(pin_number,amount)
    if pin_number == @pin
      @balance -= amount
      puts "Withdrew #{amount}."
    else
      puts pin_error
    end
end

~~
```

Comment: The `if-else` variant looks just fine to me. May I ask why you want to use a ternary instead?

Comment: This is mainly for my understanding. I'm pretty new to ruby and wanted to wrap my head around the ternary and how to use it with multiple values. Any idea why the ternary doesn't seem to work? Is it because there are two values in the "true" part?

Comment: Exactly, you have to separate the expressions with a `;` and wrap them in parentheses, i.e. `(@balance -= amount ; puts "...")`. But it makes your code hard to read and should be avoided. Oh, and there's an extra `puts` in your ternary example.

Comment: @Stefan Thank you for the reply and the note regarding the extra `puts`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a ternary operator is exactly that (an **operator**), you can't split it over multiple instructions.

However, blocks make it possible to "squash" multiple instructions into a single expression.

```rb
def my_withdraw(pin_number,amount)
  puts (
    pin_number == @pin ?
    begin
      @balance -= amount
      "Withdrew #{amount}."
    end :
    pin_error
  )
end
```

Of course, this is completely illegible and I would never recommend you use that sort of syntax in the real world. But for the sake of science, why not.

Comment: I agree with you and I real life I would prefer the if/else variant. But this makes it clearer to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

; is used to tell the Ruby that these two are different statements/expression/lines if you put two expression in a single line.

So your code will be

```
def withdraw(pin_number, amount)
    puts pin_number == pin ? ( @balance -= amount;  "Withdrew #{amount}.  New 
    balance $#{@balance}." ) : puts pin_error
 end
```